# Detecting Multipart Form Post

Tags: php, forms, multipartform-data

I have a diagnostics function that is enabled on my local development system while working on programming and it shows different aspects of what's happening, such as Session values, Form posts, Cookies etc. and it is working well. However, I came across an instance where it gives an error when posting a multi-part form. Any advice on how to correct it? With a regular form, it shows each field's name and value so that I can see what is being submitted but as it is, it is giving an ***Array to string conversion*** error in the foreach. I understand why it's doing it but I am not sure what to do to resolve it.

$ShowPosts is a Boolean that enables this bit and $s is pre-defined elsewhere. I would like this to either ignore any multipart posts or show them to me.

```
if (isset($_POST) && $ShowPosts) :
    $s .= "\n<p><h4>Form POST Values</h4>\n\n";
    foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) :
        $s .= "<strong>$key</strong> = $value\n";
    endforeach;
    if (!isset($_POST)) :
        $s .= "A POST has not been submitted";
    endif;
endif;
```

Comment: You can start checking if the `$_FILES` array is not empty and whether the `$value` is an array or string.

Comment: Thank you but it is an editable grid and has no $_FILES associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

Multipart forms has header `Content-Type` set to `multipart/form-data`, so it's easy to detect it. But it's content would end up the same as from normal forms, just enables sending binary data like files.

So your `$_POST` should not be different in `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I suggest you do `var_dump($_POST)` to see differences.

Comment: I realized after I saw my earlier reply stating that it is an editable grid without $_FILES that it doesn't need the enctype at all. Attribute it to old age. Although it apparently has nothing to do with enctype, my little snippet of code is still giving the error mentioned when I submit an editable grid form.

Comment: So can you edit question with dump of `$_POST` when error occur and when it did not?